# Almost sure covergence of exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(\lambda_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lambda_n=\infty$ and $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of exponentially distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda_n$. Then show that $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$ is not necessarily true.

Here I can observe from intuition that it is enough to show the statement is false for $\lambda_n=c+\log n,\quad\forall n\ge1$ where $c>0$ but I want to prove it mathematically using the following definition of almost sure covergence of random variables:
A sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n\ge1}\xrightarrow{d}X$, converges almost surely to the random variable $X$ if $\mathbb{P}\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|\ge\varepsilon\}=0,\quad\forall\varepsilon\ge0$ but I am struggling with properly formulating the mathematical statements here as a beginner in measure-theoretic probability theory. If someone could show me how to proceed I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sequence of independent exponential random variables $X_n\sim Exp(\lambda_n).$ Now observe that $$\mathbb{P}(\limsup|X_n|\ge \epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(X_n \ge \epsilon\quad i.o)\;.$$

Recall from the Second Borel-Cantelli lemma that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq \epsilon)=\infty$ then $\mathbb{P}(X_n \ge \epsilon\quad i.o)=1.$ If $X_n$ are exponential random variables, we can compute $\mathbb{P}(X_n\ge \epsilon)=e^{-\lambda_n\epsilon}.$ In particular, you just have to choose $\lambda_n$ so that $\sum_{n}e^{-\lambda_n\epsilon}=\infty\;$ for small values of epsilon. In particular, if you take $\lambda_n=\log(n)$, then for any $\epsilon\leq 1$, you have that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq \epsilon)=\sum_{n}n^{-\epsilon}=\infty.$$
Now Borel-Cantelli tells you that $\limsup_{n\to \infty}X_n(\omega)\geq 1$ for a.e. $\omega.$

Note that independence of $X_n$ is crucial for the second Borel-Cantelli lemma. Therefore, in order to make this proof complete, you need to establish that you can indeed construct a family of independent random variables $X_n\sim Exp(\lambda_n)$ on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P}).$ But I leave this to you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you meant that $X_n$ follows the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda_n$.

To disprove that $X_n$ vanishes almost surely as $n$ goes to $+\infty$, we can find some $\varepsilon$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $N\ge n$ which satisfies $X_N\ge\varepsilon$. In other words, we would like to find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\mathbb P(\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\{X_n\ge\varepsilon\})>0$. With the Borel-Cantelli lemma in mind, it suffices to consider that the random variables $X_n$ are independent, and find $\varepsilon>0$ such that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\mathbb P(\{X_n\ge\varepsilon\})=+\infty.
$$

Since $\mathbb P(\{X_n\ge\varepsilon\})=\exp(-\varepsilon\lambda_n)$, you can choose for instance $\varepsilon=1$ and $\lambda_n=\ln(n)$.