# Construction of a sequence of independent exponentially distributed random variables $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ with parameters $\lambda_n=\log n$.

Tags: probability-theory

My aim is to construct a sequence of exponentially distributed random variables $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with parameters $\lambda_n=\log n$ such that they are independent. But how do I find such a sequence of random variables? If someone could provide an example or provide a general idea (if any) of constructing independent random variables I would really appreciate it.

P.S. This is in correspondence to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460806/almost-sure-covergence-of-exponentially-distributed-random-variables/4460822#4460822)

Comment: If you have that the random variable $X_i \sim Exp(\log i)$, you have each factor of the product just by substituting the value of $\lambda_i$ in the law of an exponential random variable. Do you agree?

Comment: @kernel I am trying to show that the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side.

Comment: What do you mean by "strugling to find an example" ? . You are given the parameters. $X_{n}$ will have CDF $F_{X_{n}}(x)=1-e^{-x\ln(n)}$ . Also what do you mean by computing the LHS ? . You are given an equation so you substitute the value $\prod_{i=1}^{n}P(X_{i}>t)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-F_{X_{i}}(t)) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{-t\ln(n)}$

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron maybe my motive is not clear from my question above but what I am trying to do is to find an example of independent random variables such that this equation holds.

Comment: Yes, your question really does not make sense. Computing LHS for nor necessarily independent r r.v.'s is not possible and anyway it has nothing to with the construction of $(X_n)$.

Comment: Not to be rude but nothing is clear from your question above. If you are constructing independent random variables then why would you need to check independence?  . Are you asking about when do you get random variables in real life such that this occurs? .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Yes. I mean I want to find an example of such independent random variables. My motive is to establish that such independent random variables exist.

Comment: Exist???. If $n$ people independently conduct an experiment whose random outcome is distributed in the above way then you automatically get such an example. In otherwords look at kernel's comment . If you define them to be independent then why would you need to prove independence?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Please check my edited question.

Comment: Maybe you can provide us with some more context like , is this part of a problem you are solving or why at all you are interested in finding such examples , then maybe we can decipher what is it that you exactly want

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Yes, sure. This is in correspondence to this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460806/almost-sure-covergence-of-exponentially-distributed-random-variables/4460822#4460822

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting slightly lost on what constructing a probability space means here.

Indeed, if you define $X_i\sim Exp(\lambda_i)$, you are already making use of such construction.

There are four things you need to construct. The first, is a probability space. Then a $\sigma$-algebra. Finally, you need to define a measure and from there find the random variables.

I believe you will agree that $\Omega= \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ seems like a suitable choice. Then, we can just introduce the $\sigma$-algebra [generated by the functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebra_generated_by_an_arbitrary_family) $\pi_i: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\pi(\{\omega_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{R}}):= \omega_i$. The reason for choosing such a algebra will be clear in a second.

Finally, for coordinate of the sequence space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, you can define a measure $\mu_i$. Which for us will be precisely the measure associated to the law $Exp(\lambda_n)$.

If we can construct a measure $$P((a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] \times \dots) = \mu_1((a_1,b_1])\mu_2((a_2,b_2])\dots$$

Then we can define the random variables $X_i$ as $\pi_i$, remember that random variable is nothing but a measurable function (and those functions are measurable because of our choice of $\sigma$-algebras. So the only question is, under which conditions does such **product measure** exist?

The reason why probabilists never need to worry about it is  that as long each $\mu_i$ is a probability measure, we can just use the [Caratheodory extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem). This is a super general theorem that helps constructing complicated measures in infinite dimensional spaces. However, it is very simple in the countable product we defined above. See the references (or most books in introductory books in probability theory with measure theory). Hope this helps!